# Smarty variable expansion

Tags: php, smarty

If I have ($abc} in smarty template file, where $abc has been constructed in PHP using nowdoc syntax as,

```
$abc = <<<'EOT'
$key
EOT
```

is there way that smarty would fist expand the $abc, AND then expand what is within $abc, i.e. expand $key as well. Right now I get the string literal $key in the output, NOT what is inside of $key.

Reason for doing this

I have some snippets that are copied all over the place. I could place these tpl snippets in files of their own, but then that leads to explosion of files. So I have a single file that contains these snippets. But then I cannot include this big common snippet file everywhere. So I ended up constructing a PHP file that has these snippets, and then use the variables at the places I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use smarty's eval-function, but as PHP documentation says "*no parsing is done inside a nowdoc*".

Could you use heredoc instead?

```
<?
$key = 'something';
$abc = <<<EOT
$key
EOT;

// {$abc} will print something;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you tried to use sprintf?

i.e.

```
<?
$key = 'something';
$abc='there is %s here';
```

so

```
 {$abc|sprintf:$key}
```

would print "there is something here"